# Error adding Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a Foreign Key Constraint but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

USE MyTestDB
ALTER TABLE Player
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Player_Team
FOREIGN KEY (Team_Name,Team_Location)
REFERENCES TEAM(Team_Name,Team_Location)

*Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'TEAM' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Player_Team'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that your team primary key is problematic. Why can't you have two teams in a given location with the same name? They might be in different divisions. Also, copying the team all over the place is problematic, what happens when the team name changes? In general you seem to be lacking of necessary table for proper normalization. I would think you need tables for conference, division, stadium, state at the very least. Otherwise you just keep duplicating information. Also, varchar(50) for everything seems off. Why not state being char(2) for example.

Comment: Your ALTER TABLE statement should work based on the images you have shown, which makes me think they are not currently accurate.  Refresh your SSMS view of the tables, and verify they haven't changed.   If that is not the case, see if you can script out the CREATE TABLE statements and post them so that we can try to reproduce this issue.   I don't see how it can possibly be occurring if your question is accurate.

Comment: One thing you might try, first, though, is put a space after "TEAM" before the open parenthesis, and precede it with "dbo."   just to see if that makes a difference.   It shouldn't, but I'm a stickler for well-formatted SQL.

Comment: I have refreshed and tried with the space and adding "DBO." to player and team.  No dice.

Comment: Can you provide a script that will reproduce this problem?

Comment: Other than the one I copied into this thread, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the order of the column names, worked fine.  Can't believe I didn't see that before!

USE MyTestDB
ALTER TABLE dbo.Player
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Player_Team
FOREIGN KEY (Team_Location,Team_Name)
REFERENCES dbo.TEAM (Team_Location,Team_Name)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually pretty clear in describing exactly what the problem is.

You're trying to add a foreign key that says "For every Team Name and Location in the Player table, there must be a matching Team Name and Location in the Team table".

The error message is explicitly telling you it can't add the constraint because this is not the case:  there is a Team Name and Location in the Player table that DOES NOT exist in the Team table.

A query like this should list out the rows that are the problem... and you'll need to add rows with these Team Names and Locations to your Team table (or delete these rows from the Player table) before you can successfully add the constraint:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Player p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM dbo.Team t 
                    WHERE t.Team_Name = p.Team_Name AND t.Team_Location = p.Team_Location)
```

Additionally, a Foreign key reference must reference a primary key index.  Since the primary key in this case is on the first and last names, rather than the team name and location, it can't apply the FK constraint.  It needs to do this so it can do efficient look-ups and have uniqueness guarantees in order to validate the constraint.

Comment: I don't think that's what the error message is saying.

Comment: The Team table obviously needs a primary key that is "Team_Name" and "Team_Location" as well... so it can do the look up.

Comment: Well yeah, but according to the image in the question, it has one.

Comment: Looking more closely at the image... it doesn't.  The primary key is on Last_Name, FIrst_Name, not Team_Name and Team_Location, and therein lies the problem.  Updating my answer with that...

Comment: That's the PK of the Player table, not the Team table.   Look again.  : )

Comment: Then what I originally said should work.  I'm not understanding what your issue is? What do you think is wrong with my answer?  I guess I'm missing what you're trying to imply here.

Comment: The foreign key constraint needs to be added to Player table not the Team table. The team table has a primary key of team_location and team_name. The foreign key constraint references the primary keys of Team, and player has the accompanying column names. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Does the fact that the Player table has 3 primary keys matter here?